# CakePHP - Controller::flash() does not redirect

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.1, flash-message

Using `CakePHP 2.1` I have the following code

```
public function getForm($id=null){
        $this->loadModel('DynamicFormResponse');
        /**
         *  Check if form exists 
         */
        $this->form_schema= $this->DynamicForm->isValidForm($id);

        if($this->form_schema == false){
            $this->flash("Invalid form", $this->referer(
                    array('controller'=>"pages", 'action' => 'display')
                    ));           
        }
     ...
     ...
```

the problem I am facing is that, the call to `$this->flash()` renders the flash page but also continues the execution of the controller.

So Unless I do something like

```
if($this->form_schema == false){
    $this->flash("Invalid form", $this->referer(
        array('controller'=>"pages", 'action' => 'display')
    ));
    return;           
}
```

the controller does not terminate .

The main problem arises when a `_crsf_error` method is called

```
function _csrf_error() {

    $this->flash("csrf Error",  $this->referer(
            array('controller'=>"pages", 'action' => 'display')
    ));
}
```

Since the flash method does not redirect It offers no csrf protection at all.
Using `return;` after `$this->flash()` in the `_crsf_error` method does not work.

PS: ***Full code available [here](https://github.com/gautamk/SCIS/blob/0016dc738e34031ec388ec31c5ee50591472ebdd/dynForms/Controller/DynamicFormsController.php)***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flash()` does not redirect, it renders. It is very similar to the `render()` function, it will continue the execution of the script, unlike the `redirect()` function.

You just need to organize your logic accordingly, so that no other line is executed after it If you don't want to. Optionally you can use `session->setFlash()` combined with a redirect.

When dealing with serious errors like an invalid csrf token I'd recommend throwing an exception instead of rendering a nice message to the attacker. You can prettify the exception rendering using the error handler, though.

Comment: setFlash has been deprecated since version 2.7.0: You should just use Flash to create flash messages. setFlash() will be entirely removed in cake 3.0

Answer (score 6):

Although the answer above is a great explanation of what the flash() method does, to me, it did not fully answer the question but rather give a great alternative.

I personally wanted to use the flash method so I didn't have to use the session component and I found myself stuck on my flash message as well. In the cake 2.x documentation, it says that the second parameter of the flash() method is a CakePHP-relative URL. This means the following should show a message and then redirect to the index action.

```
$this->flash(__("Some message for the user here..."), array("action" => "index"));
```

My problem, and what it looks like the original poster's problem, was that it was showing you the flash message but not doing the redirect after.

I tested this thoroughly with my application and the culprit was the debug setting in core.php

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

The debug value has to be set to '0' in order for the redirect to take place. I do not know why this is the case but I tested it about 10 times and 10/10 when my debug settings were set to 1 or higher, I just got the flash message. If I set it to 0, everything works perfectly. This wasn't much of a concern to me since production environments should have this setting set to 0 anyway.

If anyone else has some insight as to why the redirect doesn't happen when debugging is on, please enlighten us all.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice catch, helped me understand what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. And after turning debug mode to 0,i got the solution of my problem.

Configure::write('debug', 0);

And why redirect was not happening with debug mode 2 there is one main cause,

your application is outputting something to the browser before the redirect header was sent. This may be caused by (non visible) white-space before or after any  . This will cause a 'headers already sent' warning, and the browser will not redirect. There are many questions regarding this situation here on StackOverflow, for example: Headers already sent by PHP