# Flash() method shows the message but not redirecting in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, flash-message

In Controller

```
public function add(){
    $this->loadModel('User'); //load model      
    if($this->request->is('post')){ 
        $filename=$this->User->checkFileUpload($this->request->data);
        $this->User->set($this->request->data); //set data to model                         
        if ($this->User->validates()){
            $datas = array(
                    'User' => array(
                                'name' => $this->request->data['User']['name'],
                                'email'=>$this->request->data['User']['email'],
                                'password'=>$this->request->data['User']['password'],
                                'image'=>$filename
                        )
                    );  
            $pathToUpload=  WWW_ROOT . 'upload/';           
            move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['User']['image']['tmp_name'],$pathToUpload.$filename);                      
            // prepare the model for adding a new entry
            $this->User->create();
            // save the data
            if($this->User->save($datas)){
                //$this->Session->setFlash('User Information has been saved!');
                return $this->Flash('User Information has been saved!',array('action' => 'index'));
                //return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        } else {
            $errors = $this->User->validationErrors; //handle errors    
        }   
    }
    //$this->layout = NULL;
    $this->viewpPath='Users';
    $this->render('add');
}
```

In above code, i used flash() method  to direct a user to a new page after an operation. This method showing the message but not redirecting in given url.
Please help me. What am i doing wrong here for redirecting with help of flash() method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP , Controller::flash() does not redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805952/cakephp-controllerflash-does-not-redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flash() does not redirect, it renders. It is very similar to the render() function, it will continue the execution of the script, unlike the redirect() function.

**but if you still want to use this**

you should use following in config file.

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

**Update**
after add this into main.php use like

```
$this->flash(__("Some message for the user here..."), array("action" => "index"));
```

it'll work perfactly . Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805952/cakephp-controllerflash-does-not-redirect) forrefrence

Comment: Sir, I am talking about Controller::flash(string $message, string|array $url, integer $pause, string $layout) . I read the CakePhp 2.x document and i want to use flash method just for practice but that was not working. Please check the link :  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html. After open this link, please search for   "Controller::flash"                                                                                      . I want to know how to use this method.

Comment: Thanks for reply but your updated code  is working if i change debug setting from 2 to 0 in core file.

Comment: read the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805952/cakephp-controllerflash-does-not-redirect.

Comment: this will only work if you will change debug parameter from 2 to 0 in core file

Comment: I finally got the answer of why i have to set 0 in debug parameter for flash method.   CakePHP debug parameter says:                                                                                                  * Production Mode:
* 0: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown. Flash messages redirect.
*
* Development Mode:
* 1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.
* 2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.
* 3: As in 2, but also with full controller dump.

Answer (score 1):

**Render != Redirect**

If you need to redirect to the referer page you can use:

```
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```

if you want redirect to different controller:

```
$this->redirect(('controller' => 'YOURCONTROLLER', 'action' => 'YOURACTION'));
```

or if you want redirect to different action in same controller:

```
$this->redirect(('action' => 'YOURACTION'));
```

Comment: Hi Javi, I know this is also possible from redirect() method but i want to do same work from flash() method.

Comment: if i want to show message with redirect url, firstly, i have to set setFlash() method for message then i have to use redirect() method. Instead of set message and then use redirect() method i want to do same thing with flash() method in single line.